# Derive equality axioms for a given problem and proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I have the following problem $a = b\land p(s(a)) \land \lnot p(s(b))$.

My task is to derive the axioms of equality and find a proof with this.
Can somebody help me, because I have no idea to do this and I found nothing really concrete about this in my script...

Comment: What do you mean with "derive the axioms of equality" ?

Comment: If $a=b$, from [equality axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) we have: $s(a)=s(b)$. And thus, again using the equality axioms, we have $p(s(a)) \to p(s(b))$

Comment: This is my first problem, i have no idea what`s meant with "derive the axioms of equality". I would use the equality axioms from the link you shared. I understand how you came to $p(s(a))→p(s(b))$, but how can i write a proof with this?

Comment: From where the problem comes from ?

Comment: I don`t know where the problem comes from, the task is only described with the information i provided in the question. There are no further information and my prof is not answering...

Comment: Maybe you have to use Resolution to prove that $a=b, p(s(a)) \vDash p(s(b))$...

Comment: Is it possible that you show me the prove for this?